# for-loop generates 'cannot insert {}, already exists' error depending on the pandas dataframe definition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a series of astronomical observations that are placed into program-generated DataFrames for each observation year (i.e., df2015, df2016, etc.) These DataFrames need to be modified in the subsequent processes, and I put all of them on the list. The method used to define the list makes a difference. An explicitly define list

```
dfs = [df2015, df2016, df2017, df2018, df2019]
```

allows further df modifications, but it does not agree with the purpose of the code - to automate the processing of standard data sets regardless of the number of years. A program-generated list

```
for yr in years:
    exec('dfs = [df' + yr + ' for yr in years]')
```

seems to be working most of the time, as in :

```
for df in dfs:
    dfX = df.dtypes
    for index, val2 in dfX.items():
        if val2 == 'float64':
            df.iloc[:,index] = df.iloc[:,index].fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

, but fails in some cases, as in:

```
for df in dfs:
    i=1
    for i in range(1, 13):
        ncol = i + (i-1) *2
        if i < 10:
            nmon = '0' + str(i)
        else:
            nmon = '' + str(i)
        df.insert(ncol, 'M' + nmon, nmon)
        i += 1
```

when a for loop with an insert statement results in an error:

```
ValueError: cannot insert M01, already exists
```

I've tried list comprehension instead of for loops, tried changing the loop nesting order (just in case), etc.

The intent of the above reference step is to convert this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
0   1   713 1623    658.0   1659.0  619 1735    526.0   1810.0  439 ... 437 1903    510.0   1818.0  542 1725    618.0   1637.0  654 1613
1   2   714 1624    657.0   1700.0  618 1736    525.0   1812.0  438 ... 438 1902    511.0   1816.0  543 1724    619.0   1636.0  655 1613
2   3   714 1625    655.0   1702.0  616 1737    523.0   1813.0  437 ... 439 1901    512.0   1814.0  544 1722    620.0   1635.0  656 1612
3   4   714 1626    654.0   1703.0  614 1738    521.0   1814.0  435 ... 440 1900    513.0   1813.0  545 1720    622.0   1634.0  657 1612
4   5   713 1627    653.0   1704.0  613 1739    520.0   1815.0  434 ... 441 1859    514.0   1811.0  546 1719    623.0   1633.0  658 1612
```

into this

```
    0   M01 D01 1   2   M02 D02 3   4   M03 ... 19  20  M11 D11 21  22  M12 D12 23  24
0   1   01  1   713 1623    02  1   658 1659    03  ... 542 1725    11  1   618 1637    12  1   654 1613
1   2   01  2   714 1624    02  2   657 1700    03  ... 543 1724    11  2   619 1636    12  2   655 1613
2   3   01  3   714 1625    02  3   655 1702    03  ... 544 1722    11  3   620 1635    12  3   656 1612
3   4   01  4   714 1626    02  4   654 1703    03  ... 545 1720    11  4   622 1634    12  4   657 1612
4   5   01  5   713 1627    02  5   653 1704    03  ... 546 1719    11  5   623 1633    12  5   658 1612
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a list of copies of the last year's dataframe. If your years list is e.g. `['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']`, then you generate a dfs as `[df2018, df2018, df2018, df2018]` which will lead to the error.

This will get you the correct result:

```
dfs = [eval('df' + yr) for yr in years]
```

It forms the required dataframe names and evaluates them so you get a list of dataframes.

Comment: Terrific! This works. Do you mind mentioning briefly why? The dfs appears to be the same when printed wither it's either of the two definitions that I started with or your definition.